# Can Blend4Web Web Player be implemented with no UI?

Tags: blend4web

I would like to put our 3d models on our website, so people can spin, pan and zoom the products to see from all angles.

But I do not want any UI elements.  Only want to see the object.

Is it possible in Blend4Web's Web Player?

This one is very nice, is it made with Blend4Web Web Player?

http://www.meisterschmuck.ch/shop/en/engagement-rings/engagement-rings-whitegold-111.2162.114-10.html

Thanks

Comment: According to [this page](https://www.blend4web.com/en/demo/), yes, that was made with Blend4Web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom, non-UI applications with Blend4Web. It is convenient to use the project manager for this:
https://www.blend4web.com/doc/en/project_manager.html#creating-a-web-player-application